# Pasting a working code into a for loop suddenly won't work anymore

Tags: python, loops

This is the code I wrote:

```
raw = read_bdf(path='data_original/', subject='s01.bdf')
raw.resample(sfreq=128, verbose=False)

indices = get_indices_where_video_start(raw)

index = indices[1]  # 29948

eeg = ['Fp1', 'Fp2']
raw.pick_channels(eeg)

raw = crop(raw, index)  # << works for index=29948
```

which correctly works.

Now I tried to generalize that procedure for each `subject` and for each `index` this way:

```
subjects = get_subjects(path)  # simply the file names in that folder

for subject in subjects:
    raw = read_bdf(path='data_original/', subject=subject)
    raw.resample(sfreq=128, verbose=False)

    indices = get_indices_where_video_start(raw)
    for index in indices:
        eeg = ['Fp1', 'Fp2']
        raw.pick_channels(eeg) 
        cropped_raw = crop(raw, index)  # won't work for index=29948
```

This works fine for `s01.bdf` and `index=16905` but won't work for `index=29948` (the next one) since I get:

> ValueError: tmax (293.96875) must be less than or equal to the max time (60.0000 s)

in my `crop` function. I debugged `tmax` values in each version and they are the same.

If you are interested, `crop` function is correctly defined as below:

```
def crop(raw: mne.io.Raw, index_trial: int) -> mne.io.Raw:
    sample_rate = get_sample_rate(raw)
    min1 = sample_rate * 60
    tmin = index_trial / sample_rate
    tmax = (index_trial + min1) / sample_rate
    cropped_raw = raw.crop(tmin=tmin, tmax=tmax)
    return cropped_raw
```

Can you help me?

Comment: If this uses an external library (I guess pydub), add an appropriate tag.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before tagging the question: "Debugging is a methodical process of finding and fixing bugs in a computer program. **IMPORTANT NOTE:** This tag is ONLY for questions about debugging techniques or the process of debugging itself, NOT for requesting help debugging your code."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was facing is related to the fact that the `crop()` function modifies the `raw` object in place. The `raw` object is modified multiple times, in the `for` loop, and this leads to unexpected behavior.

One way to fix the issue is copying the `raw` variabile using `copy()` method from MNE (or using `deepcopy()` from python), as showed below

```
subjects = get_subjects(path)

for subject in subjects:
    raw = read_bdf(path='data_original/', subject=subject)
    raw.resample(sfreq=128, verbose=False)

    indices = get_indices_where_video_start(raw)
    for index in indices:
        eeg = ['Fp1', 'Fp2']
        raw_copy = raw.copy()  # Create a copy of the original raw object
        raw_copy.pick_channels(eeg)
        cropped_raw = crop(raw_copy, index)  # Pass raw_copy as argument instead of raw
```

This fully fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A ValueError in Python indicates that there is a problem with the program typed that you tried to assign the incentive to. This should not be confused with Python types. Therefore, when a proper and valid argument is received, Python ValueError occurs.

Your Error must be happening here:

```
tmax = (index_trial + min1) / sample_rate
```

Debug this line of code and see for 3 variables that tmax is utilizing.

There type mismatch may occur.
Like but not limited to:

Null Multiplied by Integer, Integer multiplied by list, etc ...

Comment: I have already debugged that line in each "version" of the code and I get the same value for tmax